# Переменная в malloc и Valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

### Valgrind ругается на malloc()

Язык С, программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    long n, x, *args;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    args = (long*)malloc(n * sizeof(long));
    if(!args) {
        printf("Allocation error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    free(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код после ввода переменной в валгринд выдает такую ошибку:

```
==27041== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27041==    at 0x4C2CE0C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

Опытным путем выяснил, что ошибка появляется лишь когда я добавляю в malloc переменную n. То есть, например, malloc(sizeof(long) * 5); работает без ошибок, но если константу "5" заменить на переменную n - валгринд начинает ругаться.

Почему это может происходить и какая альтернатива есть?

З.Ы. Если не пускать программу через отладчик, то она абсолютно адекватно работает.

Comment: Действительно, определение помогло, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы читаете переменную `n` типа `long` при помощи формата `%d` в `scanf`. Неудивительно, что получается белиберда. Формат `%d` пригоден только для чтения значений типа `int`. Для чтения значений типа `long` нужен формат `%ld`.

(А компилятор, кстати, не предупредил вас о неправильном формате? Или вы просто проигнорировали предупреждение?)

На вашей платформе тип `long`, очевидно, шире типа `int`, что на практике приводит к тому, что из-за неправильного формата в `scanf` значение `n` "инициализируется" лишь частично. Вот именно об этом вам и трубит valgrind.

Лечить эту проблему путем предварительного обнуления `n` - это заметать проблему под ковер. Проинициализировать переменные перед `scanf` - хорошая идея, но суть ошибки отнюдь не в этом.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, теперь все понятно.
В самом деле, изменение формата на %ld решило не только данную проблему, но и проблему с выводом в printf.
Компилятор, кстати, насчет этой проблемы молчал.